# RelayJS optimistic updates that result in navigation

Tags: relayjs

Lets say you have a simple app that has a "create thing" button, and when you click it, you navigate to a new URL to edit that thing.  Now lets say you don't want to have to wait for the server to allocate you an ID before you show the editing interface.

What would you do?  Temporarily write "new" in the URL until an ID is available, and then swap it out?  Allocate an ID on the client side and hope it doesn't collide with an existing ID?  Either way you would need to stop Relay from fetching information that isn't really there yet.  How would you do that?

Comment: I'm facing the exact situation; what did you end up doing?

Answer (score 0):

Create a second route for the `new` state and give it a different `Relay.Container` that doesn't fetch any information about this object, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

I've accomplished it by passing the viewer directly to the mutation and modifying it right there.Unlike nodes fetch from relay, the newly created node won't have the **dataID** property on it thus you can easily identify it in your react component.